# Loop that uses try/except for input and loops until 'done' is entered

Tags: python, while-loop, try-catch, except

I'm kind of new to coding in Python and I'm trying to write a loop that asks for numerical input and reads it until the user inputs "done", where it will then exit the loop and print the variables: number, count and average. (not trying to store anything in a list)

I also want it to print "invalid input" and continue the loop if the user enters anything that isn't an integer, unless its "done".

Unfortunately it returns "invalid input" and keeps looping even when I enter "done". What am I doing wrong? Could anyone point me in the right direction?

```
number = 0
count = 0
avg = 0
inp = 0
while True:
    try:
        inp = int(raw_input('Enter a number: '))
        if inp is 'done':    
            number = number + inp
            count = count + 1
            avg = float(number/count)
            break
    except:
        print 'Invalid input'
print number
print count
print float(avg)
```

Comment: Have you given some thought regarding how `int(something)` can ever be equal to `'done'`????? And if miraculously `inp` becomes `'done'`, what on earth were you hoping to achieve by `number = number + inp`?????

Comment: Aside: using `except` without catching a particular exception can make it more difficult to debug code.

Comment: Thanks barak, for some reason the int() part didn't cross my mind too much. But if I didn't screw that part up so that "done" could be assigned to inp, I wanted to then take inp and add it to number then assign that value to number so that the program would later print the sum of the numbers entered throughout its the loop's iterations after breaking the loop with 'done'. Will I have to convert user input into an integer in the body of an if statement now instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sum = 0.0
count = 0
while True:
    inp = raw_input('Enter a number: ')
    if inp == 'done':
        break
    try:
        sum += int(inp)
        count += 1
    except ValueError:
        print 'Invalid input'
print sum
print count
if count != 0:  # Avoid division by zero
    print sum / count
```